# Failed to connect to the remote extension host server (Error: Missing proxy instance MainThreadDebugService)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Hey stackoverflow community i have an issue with vscode connecting to wsl2 with the following error [picture bellow] message i already searched for hours and couldnt find a solution.
reinstalled both with a clean updated version without any success

[image: 1]

Edit 1:Tried to unmount and remount folders also tried opening with high privilege's from cmd 'wsl code .' moreover i completely deleted wsl and vscode with all the extensions but still am getting the same error, i was able to reproduce more readable error, when opening a project it prompts with

> unable to resolve resource vscode-re...://%ubuntu-22.04/file_path

Edit 2: opening WSL, 'New WSL window using distro' works fine but i cant open any directory, without it producing the error in Edit 1

Answer (score 9):

I got the same issue. I use Windows and I open the folder in vscode in this way:

shift+right-click the folder -> open linux shell -> type in "code ."

when vscode opens, the error does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

For me this was due to the secondary sidebar being visible.

After disabling it via `View -> Appearance -> Secondary Side Bar`, WSL2 starts up fine again.

Comment: It happened to me on Mac M1 as well.
But your solution worked very well.
Thank you 

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and needed to run..

```
$ code
Updating VS Code Server to version  97dec172d3256f8ca4bfb2143f3f76b503ca0534
Removing previous installation...
Installing VS Code Server for x64 (97dec172d3256f8ca4bfb2143f3f76b503ca0534)
Downloading: 100%
Unpacking: 100%
Unpacked 2389 files and folders to /home/dmitri/.vscode-server/bin/97dec172d3256f8ca4bfb2143f3f76b503ca0534.
```

in WSL2 to update the WSL2 server. Then uninstalling and reinstalling the WSL extension from VSCode did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same.

If your project is on another drive mount it and
run vscode as administrator.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it using `ctrl` + `shift` + `p`, then type `WSL` and chose `WSL: Open folder in WSL...` and it works ok.

Answer (score 0):

Top answer says to: shift+right-click the folder -> open linux shell -> type in "code ."

However, I could not get this to work. It only flickerd a terminal window quickly.

I opened the linux shell, got into the directory of my project, then typed "code" and suddenly I got this, and it opened vscode.

```
Installing VS Code Server for x64 (0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2)
```

Once that was done, I was able to use `shift+ctrl+p` then choose `WSL: Open folder in WSL...`, and could open this folder again after restarting vscode without running from the linux terminal.

Answer (score -1):

I am the same.
I also reinstalled VSCode and Docker, but nothing changed.

In the "Remote - Containers" tutorial, I was able to connect without any problems.
It doesn't work with my code.